# Merge multiple columns into matrix python

Tags: python, csv, merge, zip, data-processing

I have several columns in python that I'm ultimately trying to merge.  Right now I'm using the zip function, but after I merge the columns I output them as CSV and the format is terrible (instead of keeping the columns separate, zip is combining columns as I add new ones).  Here is an example:

```
col1 = [text1, text2, text3, etc]
col2 = [str1, str2, str3, etc.]
col3 = [num1, num2, num3, etc.]
```

I want them combined like this:

```
[[text1, str1, num1],
 [text2, str2, num2],
 [text3, str3, num3]]
```

from there I will be able to output that matrix as a csv where the columns are all separate. Right now it looks like this:

My code

```
file_weights = similarity[0]
file_ranking = zip(filtered_and_cleaned, case_id)[1:]
file_ranking_2 = zip(file_ranking, file_weights)[1:]
```

the output

```
[[text1 str1, num1],
 [text2 str2, num2],
 [text3 str3, num3]]
```

I understand why what I'm doing doesn't work, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Im ay be wrong. But I guess the output after writing the contents to csv that you've shared here  is wrong. As in, you have given the desired list instead of the expected list.

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) of a pointer to the list of your columns should do the trick!

```
col1 = [text1, text2, text3]
col2 = [str1, str2, str3]
col3 = [num1, num2, num3]
print zip(*[col1,col2,col3])
```

In Python 3 [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator. Therefore the `list` of your result wil give the desired output!.

That is,

```
print list(zip(*[col1,col2,col3]))
```

Output format will be something as follows!:

```
[[text1, str1, num1],
 [text2, str2, num2],
 [text3, str3, num3]]
```

Hope it helps.

Happy coding!

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!